# Bosch Cordless Drill Keeps Cutting Out

Tags: drill

I have a Bosch PSB 1800 LI-2 cordless drill.  I've had it for about 2-3 years, but it doesn't have many "miles on the clock".  It's a lovely bit of kit and I've had no problems with it, until recently.  I was trying to remove some particularly stubborn stripped screws, using screw extractor bits.  I managed to remove some of them, then my drill developed a fault.

It started cutting out intermittently.  The battery is fully charged, so I know it's not a lack of power.  When I pull the trigger gently to run it on anything up to about half-power, it might work for up to a minute before cutting out.  If I try  to run it on anything more than about half-power, it cuts out within 3 seconds. Either way, it's not much use for any serious jobs.

Has anybody had similar problems with their drills?  Does anybody know whether this is something that can be fixed, or do I need to buy a new drill?

Comment: I have a similar problem that I haven't fixed yet.  Removing the battery and replacing it a few times seems to fix it, so I _think_ it's in the battery contacts, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's a brushless DC motor on that drill, so it's not bad brushes as it would have been in the past. It's either some bad contacts on the battery connector as JPhi1618 said, or the control electronics are faulting out, in which case the drill is trash. I'd try pulling the battery and checking the contacts, maybe cleaning them with some electrical contact cleaner (you can usually find that at automotive stores). Don't use sand paper on them however, it does more harm than good.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you tried a different battery? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Another common problem is a failure in the trigger switch.  These can wear out or get crud in them and then they don't always work reliably.  Bosch has replacement parts available for most models.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, a bad cell in the battery may show charged but any real load on the battery and it is dead. I had this problem with rigid brand and they are all in boxes now as they did not stand behind there lifetime battery warranty. +

Answer (score 3):

If the drill is a few years older as you mentioned i would say its likely NOT a brushless motor, in fact everything i was able to research says nothing about it being brushless, so its safe to assume it is NOT, that being said its the motor. I know you said its got low miles and i believe you, unfortunatley you just had some bad luck and for whatever reason your motor is giving out. Fortunatley for you most traditional brushed motors can easily be replaced and put back to work. Unfortunatley while doing my research i didnt come arcoss any vendors that still had these particular motors in stock. So if you can find it then your all set to go, if not than youll be shopping for a replacment within the week. My advice would be to take it slow and treat her like the smallest bump will be the last bump... because it probably will.